# Запуск игры на pascal в браузере

Tags: php, delphi, сервер, браузер

Нужно запустить игру, написанную на pascal на сайте, чтоб она работала онлайн в браузере. Вариант переписывать на другие языки вручную не подходит. Возможно ли такое? Я наткнулся на CGI, пока не совсем понял что это, оно может мне помочь?

Можно ли как-то перекомпилировать его, чтоб работал в браузере?

Comment: Это невозможно!

Comment: @naym, ну прям таки.

Comment: @Micov15, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Простого и хорошего способа у этого нет.

Разработчики Hedgewars для запуска игры в браузере пишут собственный транслятор подмножества паскаля в Си, далее код на Си компилируют в LLVM, а LLVM в JavaScript при помощи EmScripten.

Comment: а если игра на Delphi?И можно по подробее?

Comment: С delphi ситуация аналогична.

Подробнее про hedgewars: http://lists.freepascal.org/pipermail/fpc-devel/2013-February/031397.html

Answer (score 1):

Нет, CGI вам тут, скорее всего, не поможет, так как он выполняет программу на сервере и просто отсылает результат ее выполнения клиенту.

Браузеры поддерживают ограниченное количество языков: JavaScript, VBScript,
 ActionScript(flash) и Java, остальное Вы в нем не запустите. Так что надо либо переписывать на эти языки, либо, как сказал в ответе [[@Дож](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6)](/users/865/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6), автоматизировать этот процесс транслятором. Но я не знаю, что это должны быть за задача и игра, чтобы пойти на написание транслятора.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае:

- Перепишите игру на клиентский язык (JS)
- Напишите транслятор
- Используйте GaaS (Транслируйте игру с сервера на клиент путем стриминга, см. Nvidia Grid)